# Java - How to programatically get a stack trace on a remote process

Tags: java, stack-trace, remote-debugging

How can you, from a Java program, get a stack trace on a known thread running in a remote VM?

Does the remote JVM need to be running with any special switches?

Comment: it's on the same box - so not that remote but a different jvm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you really need to do this programatically from within Java (I guess so given that your question says so explicitly)?

Anyway, just incase not,  then on Linux you can just do this on the command line:

```
kill -3 <pid>
```

EDIT: for programmatic access start the application with JMX enabled, connect to it via JMX and use  [ThreadMXBean.getThreadInfo](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/management/ThreadMXBean.html) to get a stack trace for each running thread.

If you have multiple JVM's on the same machine, each will need it's own distinct JMX port, you can handle this by repeatedly trying to select one from a pool, at random, and logging out the result.

See [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/remote/custom.html) for step by step on creating a custom JMX client.

Comment: Yes - specifically through Java

Comment: JConsole can generate a stack trace (so assuming you can run the app with JMX enabled) ...take a look at the MBeans that JConsole triggers to generate the stacktrace in the console (all the names are exposed through the console). You could call these yourself if you wire up to the app via jmx,

Comment: Here you go - you could connect via JMX and call ThreadMXBean.getThreadInfo(long[], int) : http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/management/ThreadMXBean.html#getThreadInfo(long[], int)

Comment: Where do you specify the pid of the remote JVM?

Comment: Well with JMX you need  each process on the same machine using a distinct port for JMX to run on. If you have multiple processes you could have each try a random port within some range on startup, and retry until it finds a free. This might be overkill for what you want, but running with JMX enabled does have it's own advantages.

Comment: I still don't see how to get the MBean of a remote JVM?  Do you think you ould send me a tiny code snippet please?

Comment: You do something like this (See creating a client):   http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/remote/custom.html